# C# compare two strings that spans on multiple lines

Tags: c#, string-comparison, multilinestring

I am trying to compare 2 strings that spans on multiple lines.

Example:

```
string myStr1= "Microsoft’s approach to IoT <br>
Pham Tien Dung – Developer Evangelist Microsoft Vietnam"

string myStr2 = "Microsoft’s approach to IoT <br>
Pham Tien Dung – Developer Evangelist Microsoft Vietnam"
```

Approaches:

1. Tried with verbatim string as follows.

   ```
   string myStr3 = @myStr1
   string myStr4 = @myStr2
   ```

and proceeded with string comparison and received an error.

2.Tried with regular expression(Removed white spaces, new line). Still received an error.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the error? Also how are you doing the comparison? Show code

Comment: This C# code is invalid. Show us how your string is initialized and how it actually looks like.

Comment: You can compare string with newline. You don't need to remove them.

Comment: The code `@myStr1` is not a verbatim string, the `@` needs to be prefixed to a string literal, not a string variable. For example `@"blah <br> blah"`

Comment: check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/yTE23v, that's how you should do

Answer (score 1):

This should work, notice where `@` is located:

```
string myStr1= @"Microsoft’s approach to IoT <br>
Pham Tien Dung – Developer Evangelist Microsoft Vietnam";

string myStr2 = @"Microsoft’s approach to IoT <br>
Pham Tien Dung – Developer Evangelist Microsoft Vietnam";

bool areStringsSame = myStr1 == myStr2;
//or, like this:
bool stringsSame = myStr1.Equals(myStr2);
```

Comment: or third option `bool stringsSame = string.Equals(myStr1,myStr2);`

Comment: @Nino , well, myStr1, myStr2 are read from external source.  So, I just tried with above mentioned code snippet. Kindly have a look atit.

Comment: @Dhanaprabhu are you reading the strings from files?

Comment: @ElectricRouge am reading n-number of values from Web table and trying to compare it with the expected result from excel sheet through List. But, when comparing through the list the verbatim is getting ignored.

Comment: @Dhanaprabhu Check the new line characters. My guess is one has `\n` and other has `\r\n`

Comment: @ElectricRouge you are right. But, when we are iterating the List values, new line characters \n  \r\n are getting ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply [Equal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and your code might look like this:

```
string myStr1= @"Microsoft’s approach to IoT <br>
Pham Tien Dung – Developer Evangelist Microsoft Vietnam"

string myStr2 = @"Microsoft’s approach to IoT <br>
Pham Tien Dung – Developer Evangelist Microsoft Vietnam"

if (myStr1.Equals(myStr2 )) // Yes
```

**If you are wondering WHY I PUT @ before a string = > explanation is below!**

It marks the string as a verbatim string literal - anything in the string that would normally be interpreted as an escape sequence is ignored.

So for example `"C:\\Users\\John" is the same as @"C:\Users\John"`